# Angular 12: injected service is undefined

Tags: angular

When trying to inject one service into another - both beeing providedIn: 'root', the injected service is undefined:

```
@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root',
})
export class MessageService {
}

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class ColDefService {

  tableId: string;

  constructor(
    private valueGetterService: ValueGetterService,
    private messageService: MessageService
  ) {
  }

}
```

This is the error I am getting.

```
    core.js:6456 ERROR TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'messageService')
    at getAngebotGemeindNameAndNr (value-getter.service.ts:97)
    at ExpressionService.push.52107.ExpressionService.evaluate (ag-grid-community.cjs.js:32392)
    at ValueService.push.52107.ValueService.executeValueGetter (ag-grid-community.cjs.js:28459)
    at ValueService.push.52107.ValueService.getValue (ag-grid-community.cjs.js:28288)
    at CellComp.push.52107.CellComp.getValue (ag-grid-community.cjs.js:21414)
    at CellComp.push.52107.CellComp.getValueAndFormat (ag-grid-community.cjs.js:21397)
    at new CellComp (ag-grid-community.cjs.js:20699)
    at RowComp.push.52107.RowComp.newCellComp (ag-grid-community.cjs.js:42687)
    at ag-grid-community.cjs.js:42641
    at Array.forEach (<anonymous>)
```

Comment: Please use code blocks instead of links to third-party image sites to provide context to your problem.

Comment: Did you import the right MessageService? Also, could I suggest you share code snippets in your question as opposed to sharing images? Cheers :)

Comment: Sorry for the inadequate initial post - I am a newbe regarding posting on stackoverflow.

Comment: How are you using this service as per exception details it looks like it will used under ag-grid. Kindly share ag-grid code where this has been used.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.